# Display Static file Django and rest-framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I need to Display the static file, I follow Django document but it is not displayed.

1.In Models file

```
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

2.In urls.py file

```
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.conf.urls.static import static
  ...
  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

3.In settings.py file

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'lost_items/static/')
 ]

 STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'


 MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

4. finally, I run this command

   python manage.py collectstatic

when I GET API, the image in this URL

```
"image": "http://localhost:8000/media/images/n73.jpg"
```

So, When I click on it, I get the page not found, and:

```
The current path, media/images/money.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Add media urls as same as static url in your urls.py

Comment: could explain it in code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the images was uploaded by the user.

add this to your urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

All uploaded files or "media" will have the Media URL. It only makes sense that Media URL must be added to urls.py